# Trying to find a string in a XML file with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I had a KML file that i've changed into an XML and i can output any information from it with no problem. But my "description" tag has a CDATA block inside which has HTML code.
Im using PHP to echo something if "description" tag contains "some HTML code". But in my XML file, the "td" tags (which are in a CDATA block as i said) are separated by two line breaks and because of that my if statement doesnt work.

My PHP:

```
$a=array();
foreach($xml->Document->Folder->Placemark as $casa) {
    if(strpos($casa->description,'<td>Mob_Reduzi</td>**WHAT TO PUT HERE**<td>0</td>') !== false){
       echo "BLA BLA BLA"
    }
}
```

I've tried that PHP code with line break unicodes between those tags but nothing worked. Eliminate the line break is not an option right now because there are thousands of those lines.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"\n"` (note the `"`, won't work with `'`) is the linebreak char. however, you need to use EXACTLY what's in the string. if it came from a win box, it'd be `"\r\n"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what type of line breaks they are (which usually depends on the OS), you can use one of the following escape sequences to represent a line break in a string:

- `\n` for Unix/OS X
- `\r\n` Windows

Note that these are only interpreted by PHP inside double quoted strings. So with that in mind (and assuming there's always 2 line breaks like you mentioned in the question) you can change your check to this:

Unix/OS X line breaks:

`if(strpos($casa->description,"<td>Mob_Reduzi</td>\n\n<td>0</td>") !== false){`

Windows line breaks:

`if(strpos($casa->description,"<td>Mob_Reduzi</td>\r\n\r\n<td>0</td>") !== false){`

If there are a variable/unpredictable number of line breaks, you're probably better off using regex: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: thanks that works finally, i already tried that but it wasnt using the right quotes